# SharePoint create site option

Tags: sharepoint, office365

I am not getting Create site option on the sharepoint. Currently I have F1 license. Please guide me how to get the sharepoint site access. Is it license related? Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft 365 Family doesn’t contain SharePoint Online. Generally, the Microsoft 365 or Office 365 plans below contain SharePoint Online service:

[image]

You can choose to purchase the Microsoft 365 plan or Office 365 plan above. For more details, you can refer to this article: [Microsoft 365 and Office 365 plan options](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/office-365-platform-service-description/office-365-plan-options).

If you just want to purchase SharePoint Online service, you can also purchase SharePoint Online Plan1 or SharePoint Online Plan 2. For more details, you can refer to this article: [Compare SharePoint Online options](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/sharepoint/compare-sharepoint-plans).